# Get argument type from a decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

Is there a way to find the argument type of a decorated method in TypeScript?

For example, if I have a class like this:

```
class ExPolicies {

    @Policy
    public onArticleCreated(event: ArticleCreated) {
        console.log(event)
    }
}
```

I want to be able to find the type of the argument in the decorator definition:

```
function Policy<T>(
    target: Object,
    key: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(event: T) => void>
) {
    // Here I want to retrive the type ArticleCreated
    return descriptor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution, we have information about argument's type with the Reflect api :

```
Reflect.getMetadata("design:paramtypes", target, key)
```